# Best process on Windows XP SP3 to update old C++/DirectX 7-8 code from a book to C#/SlimDX or DirectX 9?

Tags: c#, c++, directx, port, porting

I am diving back into the world of programming. In a few months, after I have grown competent in C#, I'm going to use an old book, that C++ Terrain Engine thing Charles Rivers released, and maybe a few other titles I have.

The problem is I am using C# and not C++. Also, I don't care how much better C++ may be. As well I don't want or need statements such as, "It takes more than one person to make a game engine..." or "You shouldn't do this until (some condition)..." or anything else.

**Note well!** In my mind, in my imagination. I have build and created my own GCS, by myself, in C#. I have been dreaming about it, seeing its features clearly, for some time now. In other words, I have already made this and it is only a matter of time before it takes physical shape. All I am doing now is manifesting the reality I created. To take steps to do so I am learning programming and planning ahead so I can test what I call flow. I don't expect you to agree with my mindset here, I just ask that you respect it.

So, what would be the best process, in your opinion, to take the C++ code from an old book and write a C# equivalent?

Next,because Microsoft screwed things up with DirectX, as I'm sure many of you know, most of the code in these books will fail to work in the DirectX department. So what is the best way to take old DirectX commands and change them to newer DX9 commands for Windows XP? Or perhaps SlimDX?

I figure there has to be some way, some process, that allows a coder to take a 2-10 year old book and write functioning code from it. In essence I am asking what is this process?

Thank you for reading. I appreciate your help -
- DreamBliss

Comment: Porting old DirectX code does not really make sense, since the pipeline has changed quite a bit since then. In older DirectX version (DX8 and older), you had a fixed function pipeline, and configured what should be done. With newer DX (9 through 11), you have vertex and pixel shaders written in HLSL or similar, to manipulate the data as you seem fit. I would try to get the general idea of your code, and translate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I've ended up delving back into C++. And I have figured out how to get old DirectX code to run. You can watch my new video tutorial series, explaining exactly how to do it, here:
http://adifferentpath.blog.com/using-old-directx-code-links-and-resources/

Comment: OK the link is now here:http://adifferentpath.blog.com/using-old-source-code-links-and-resources/ and at the link you will find the videos and a description of the series.